# CakePHP need advice on organizing models

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, database-design

I'm developing a site like "yellow pages" with more complex DB than I had ever experienced before.

For example:
This DB has 3 tables: 
1. organisations – with some general information. 
2. services - with list of all services that can be provided. 
3. relation table.

Organisations table structure:

```
id    name         city       phone      etc.
1     CompanyName  Farewell   987-65-43
```

Services table structure:

```
id    ServiceType  
1     purchase  
-----
2     sale  
-----
3     exchange
```

etc..
you get the point

And relation table structure:

```
id    OrganisationID   ServId      
1     1                2
----
2     1                3
----   
3     1                6
----
4     2                3
```

In website output I need a list of all organisations with all the services they provide.

I can't fully understand (even after reading Linking Models Together section in the CookBook) how I should combine all this tables using Cake's syntax and conventions.

I'll be glad if anyone can provide me a Cake's model/model's (how many I need?) example with ability to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment on your question so I'll ask here...

Organisations can have many services and services can have many organisations? Is it `HABTM` relationship? (Just checking...)

If it is, I'll then edit this and try to give you the answer. :)

EDIT:

**TABLES**

```
1. table: organisations
2. table: services
3. table: organisations_services (sorted alphabetically)


1. table: id, name, city...
2. table: id, service_type
3. table: id, organisation_id, service_id (singular, sorted alphabetically)
```

**MODELS**

Organisation - inside your organisation model you must have:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Service');
```

Service - inside your service model you must have:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Organisation');
```

And that's all. Everything else leave to the beautiful Cake. :) If you don't understand something, feel free to ask and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) you can get more information.

Comment: Yes, organisation can provide many services and services can have many organisations.

Comment: Ok... Give me a few minutes... :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I only can test it tomorrow so if something went wrong I'll ask your advice :).

Comment: No problem. You can ask me here or you can send me an e - mail provided on my profile. Good luck!